# YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor ViewPager

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have trouble using the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment inside a (Support)ViewPager. Everything works fine except when I put the video on Fullscreen and then reduce it. It won't play anymore inside the Viewpager.

Logcat error :

> W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to
>   unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not
>   contained inside its ancestor
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView{2fcbbe15 V.E.....
>   ......ID 0,0-1920,919}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and
>   that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom:
>   -281 (these should all be positive).

Here's my (simplified) code :

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home_no_news_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/home_home_title_no_news"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

GSYoutubeFragment.java

```
public class GSYoutubeFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, OnBackPressedListener, YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener {
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_ID = "VIDEO_ID";

    String mVideoId;
    YouTubePlayer mPlayer;
    boolean mIsFullScreen;

    public static GSYoutubeFragment newInstance(String videoId) {
        GSYoutubeFragment frag = new GSYoutubeFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(KEY_VIDEO_ID, videoId);

        frag.setArguments(args);

        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mVideoId = getArguments().getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID);
        }

        initialize("myapikey, you won't see it :)", this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ((GSActionBarActivity) getActivity()).addOnBackPressedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        ((GSActionBarActivity) getActivity()).removeOnBackPressedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        mPlayer = youTubePlayer;
        youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(this);
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(mVideoId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPlayer != null && mIsFullScreen) {
            ((GSActionBarActivity)getActivity()).shouldIgnoreCurrentBackPressEvent();

            mPlayer.setFullscreen(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean fullscreen) {
        mIsFullScreen = fullscreen;
    }
}
```

GSHomeFragment.java

```
public class GSHomeTabletFragment extends AbsGSHomeFragment implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    private HomeCursorPagerFragmentAdapter mNewsCursorPagerFragmentAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mNewsCursorPagerFragmentAdapter = new HomeCursorPagerFragmentAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), this, null);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mNewsCursorPagerFragmentAdapter);

        mSlidingTabLayout = getSlidingTabs();
        mSlidingTabLayout.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mNewsCursorPagerFragmentAdapter.setParentFragment(this);

        mSlidingTabLayout.showTabs();
        mSlidingTabLayout.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mSlidingTabLayout.hideTabs();
        mSlidingTabLayout.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewsLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        mNewsCursorPagerFragmentAdapter = new HomeCursorPagerFragmentAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), cursor);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mNewsCursorPagerFragmentAdapter);

        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(LOADER_NEWS_ID);
    }
```

Comment: where is your YouTubePlayerView in your XML file?

Comment: hi! Did you solve the problem?